# Spring - Host reference is HTTP on an HTTPS server

Tags: java, spring, restlet

I have two `SpringServer` servers;

HTTP

```
<bean id="server" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServer">
    <constructor-arg value="http" />
    <constructor-arg value="${server.port}" />
    <property name="parameters">
        <props>
            <prop key="tracing">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

HTTPS

```
<bean id="httpsServer" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServer">
  <constructor-arg value="https" />
  <property name="parameters">
    <props>
      <prop key="sslContextFactory">org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory</prop>
      <prop key="keyStorePath">C:/store/ks.jks</prop>
      <prop key="keyStorePassword">pwd</prop>
      <prop key="keyPassword">pwd</prop>
      <prop key="keyStoreType">JKS</prop>
   </props>
 </property>
</bean>
```

I then load these servers into a `SpringComponent`:

```
<bean id="component" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
 <property name="serversList">
    <list>
      <ref bean="server" />
      <ref bean="httpsServer"/>
    </list>
 </property>
 <property name="clientsList">
    <list>
     <value>file</value>
     <value>clap</value>
     <value>http</value>
     <value>https</value>
    </list>
 </property>
 <property name="defaultHost" ref="defaultHost" />
</bean>
```

My problem is that the host reference is always `http://localhost` even when I am on `https`. This is causing timeouts on chrome because of the **Content Security Policies** that it has.

Sample output:

> 2017-04-06  15:27:38    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -   -   443 GET /client/app/partials/login.html -   200 1850    0   1   http://localhost    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36 https://localhost/app/login

Answer (score 0):

According to Restlet's [change log](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/2.3/changelog), on older versions this is caused by an HTTPS server that is not properly registered. Upgrading to restlet 2.3.9 fixed the problem.